# Redux form state is lost when user navigates away

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-form

I have a simple React app, where I display a redux-form dropdown. The user selects an option from this dropdown and this option is displayed in the Header component.

This option is stored in the redux store thanks to redux-form, and accessed via the formValueSelector function (again from redux-form lib).

However, this user selected option is lost in the redux store when the user directs to a new page in the app..  How can I fix this?

I've tried wrapping my Header component with withRouter, but that didn't seem to fix it..

Here's my Homepage component with the redux-form:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const centres = ['Ponders End', 'North Finchley', 'Hendon', 'Walthamstow']

const renderCentreDropdown = ({ input, label }) => {
  console.log({ input })
  return (
    <div className="inline field">
      <label>{label}</label>
      <select {...input} >
        <option value="">Select a centre...</option>
        {centres.map(centre => (
          <option value={centre} key={centre}>
            {centre}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}

let HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="ui middle aligned center aligned grid">
      <div className="column">
        <form className="ui large form">
          <div className="ui segment">
            <Field name="centreSelect" label="Select a centre: " component={renderCentreDropdown} />
            <div className="field">
              <div className="ui left icon input">
                <i className="user icon" />
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail address" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <div className="ui left icon input">
                <i className="lock icon" />
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Link to="/todaysclass" className="ui fluid large pink submit button">Login</Link>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

HomePage = reduxForm({
  form: 'centreSelectForm'
})(HomePage)

export default HomePage
```

and here's my Header component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import moment from 'moment'
import { formValueSelector } from 'redux-form'

class Header extends React.Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div className="ui secondary menu" >
        <h2 className="ui dividing header">Axis Tuition Centre{(this.props.centreName) ? ` - ${this.props.centreName}` : ''} </h2>
        <div className="right menu" >
          {moment().format('Do MMMM YYYY')}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const selector = formValueSelector('centreSelectForm')

export default connect(state => {
  const centreName = selector(state, 'centreSelect')
  return {
    centreName
  }
})(Header)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/8.2.0/docs/gettingstarted.md/) destroys the state of form when the component in which form is present unMounts, so to presist the state of the form and access it in other components or after routing, set `destroyOnUnmount: false` in `reduxForm` in `HomePage`.

This will work for you:

```
HomePage = reduxForm({
  form: 'centreSelectForm',
  destroyOnUnmount: false
})(HomePage)
```

Comment: arh! I can't believe I couldn't figure out something so simple!  Thanks man!